# Qual a melhor maneira de implementar Schema no HTML?

Tags: seo, schema, microdata

Dando uma pesquisada na internet vi que o Google recomenda a implementação do Schema via JSON/LD.

Por mais que eu tenha pesquisado bastante, não encontrei nenhuma resposta tão específica. A minha primeira dúvida, é se há alguma diferença no desempenho entre colocar o script dentro de `<head>` ou ao final de `</body>`.

E caso haja uma perca de desempenho utilizando ao final de `</body>` (ou no meio do corpo), seria preferível usar o formato Microdata?

Comment: Marquei como duplicata e a outra é uma pergunta diferente. Uma das perguntas já foi respondida sim e não sei como pode ser mais específica. A outra pergunta seria interessante um contexto maior.

Comment: Eu não concordo com o fechamento e votei para reabrir, tem muito mais coisa na pergunta do que simplesmente se um JS deve vir no início ou fim do documento. Não é só questão de renderização de  página e sim como o crawler do Google funciona. Nada de SEO, microdata ou schema é abordado nas duplicadas... E acredito que a "*caso haja uma perca de desempenho*" o AP esteja falando em relação ao SEO e não a renderização, já que nem é possível dizer se o bot do Google chega a renderizar alguma coisa...

Comment: JSON/LD são metadados no formato JSON para contornar o problema de que a grande maioria dos desenvolvedores não sabem escrever HTML (corretamente). Sabem sintaxe, mas não sabem semântica. A única diferença é que aumenta o payload da página, pois são algumas centenas de bytes a mais para entregar ao cliente. Para sistemas de indexação de conteúdo, que analisarão o JSON/LD, não deve fazer muita diferença a localização. Se o sistema só faz isso, idealmente seria melhor colocar o quanto antes, pois os dados serão analisados através de um stream e poderá ignorar todo o resto.

Comment: Para a grande maioria das páginas essa possível diferença será desprezível e mesmo se existir nem fará diferença para você, porque isso afetará apenas na aplicação que está indexando o conteúdo e depende somente da implementação da mesma, podendo, inclusive, algumas sugerirem colocar o JSON no início da página e outras no final. Para v você, coloque onde for mais conveniente.

Comment: Para vc não perder tempo esperando que reabra, ou não, aqui vc pode se informar, https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data?hl=pt-BR vc vai ver que o JSON pode vir em qualquer lugar, e que inclusive ele pode ser injetado na página por outro JS que mesmo assim o Google vai interpretar. Vc não precisa se preocupar com desempenho da página ou rankeamento nesse caso. O no geral o uso de microdata e do jason pode depender do tamanho do projeto etc, pq fica trabalho escrever o schma direto na tag, é quase o mesmo que fazer um site inteiro escrevendo o CSS direto nas tags

Comment: Acredito que o problema do fechamento começou porque o AP chamou `JSON-LD` de script, aí deu a entender que a dúvida dele seria respondida na duplicada. Enfim, JSON-LD pode aparecer no `<head>` ou no `<body>` e acredito que não mudança de performance pois seu MIME Type, `application/ld+json` não é executado pelo browser, apenas lido. Como não é JS nem CSS, não há bloqueio em renderização.

Comment: Talvez tenha me expressado de forma errada, quando falei em desempenho quis dizer da forma como o Google analisa, e não do desempenho do meu site. De qualquer forma, fiz a pergunta tendo quase certeza de que tinha algum atraso na renderização sim, visto que os teste de velocidades foram melhores quando tirei o JSON/LD do meu <head>. 

Estou na dúvida agora. Pra mim não seria problema fazer a marcação via microdata, pois ainda estou iniciando o projeto. Mesmo assim, o JSON ao final de <body> parece ser a melhor, já que ele é recomendado.